# How to get pygame to quit after playing a song

Tags: python, pygame, quit

I'm trying to use this [tutorial](http://guzalexander.com/2012/08/17/playing-a-sound-with-python.html) to run pygame instead of Mplayer in my script:

So, in the code:

```
import pygame     
pygame.init()
song = pygame.mixer.Sound(my_song.ogg)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
song.play()
while True:
   clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
print "done"   # not appears
exit()
```

The song is playing well, but "done" is never printed in the console. The program stays in the loop...
How to fix it ?
Thanks

Edit: I found this, it's working well, with a 10 second song:

```
import pygame
import time     
pygame.init()
song = pygame.mixer.Sound(son)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
song.play()
while True:
  clock.tick(60)
  time.sleep(10)
  break
pygame.quit()
print "done"
exit()
```

Comment: `while True` is an infinite loop. What did you expect it to do?

Comment: I want the program play the .ogg, and after print "done" (or something else), exit() for example. Without this loop, the song is not playing..

Comment: you should see official pygame documentation http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html

Comment: I found a solution (I don't know if it's the best, but it work)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have several problems with the two examples provided.

First:

```
while True:
    clock.tick(60)
```

is an infinite loop in any context, not just `pygame`, and will never exit.

Next:

```
while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    time.sleep(10)
    break
```

will just `break` on its first time through the loop and is equivilent to

```
clock.tick(60)
time.sleep(10)
```

which is why it works fine for a `10` second song.

If you want to use `pygame.mixer.Sound` you should do it like this, using [`Sound.get_length()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.get_length)

```
import pygame
import time     
pygame.init()
song = pygame.mixer.Sound("my_song.ogg")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
song.play()
time.sleep(song.get_length()+1)  # wait the length of the sound with one additional second for a safe buffer
pygame.quit()
print "done"
exit()
```

`pygame` recommends using [`mixer.music`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html) for things like this:

```
import pygame
import time     
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("my_song.ogg")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
    continue
pygame.quit()
print "done"
exit()
```

[See this answer for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691452/in-pygame-or-even-in-python-in-general-how-would-i-create-a-loop-that-keeps-e)

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable for your loop and then check mixer.music.get_busy() to determine whether your loop should stop.

```
from pygame import mixer

filename =  "mymusic.mp3"

x = mixer.init(frequency=44100)
mixer.music.load(filename)
mixer.music.play()

run = True
while run: 
    # ..do some stuff
    pos = mixer.music.get_pos() / 1000
    print('pos', pos)
    
    if mixer.music.get_busy() == False:
        run = False
```